# Display data on a Jtable after excuting a search

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

basically currently my code is searching for the first name or surname in the table. Once the search has been done, for example 'Peter' , what will occur is the data will be placed into the text boxes.

The issue is I want the data to be displayed onto my table, I have tried this many times but it does not seem to work, I have tried using this line of code. The 'table_stats' is the name of the table. table_stats.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(Result));

I am pretty new to this, can any one please help, much appreciated thank you!

```
private void searchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
      String sql = "select * from statistics where first_name =? "  ;
       String sql2 = "select * from statistics where surname =? "  ;
      Prepared=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      Prepared=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
      Prepared.setString (1, search.getText());
      Result = Prepared.executeQuery();
      if(Result.next()){
          String add1 = Result.getString("player_id");
          player_id.setText(add1);
          String add2 = Result.getString("first_name");
          first_name.setText(add2);
          String add3 = Result.getString("surname");
          surname.setText(add3);
          String add4 = Result.getString("goal_scored");
          goal_scored.setText(add4);
          String add5 = Result.getString("assist");
          assist.setText(add5);



      }

    }
    catch(Exception e)


    {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the DefaulTableModel: (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

Or you can implement your own subclass of AbstracTableModel: (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html)

Anyway you should separate code like querying a database table from your GUI code (for example create a separate class with a method getPlayers which returns a table model).